# Redis error while reading line from the server

Tags: tcp, redis, predis

Below are my current values dealing with tcp and open files on my linux system:

```
$cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max  # outputs 1,624,164.
$cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog  #outputs 1,048,576
$cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn  # output 65535
$ulimit -a  # open files = 1,024,000, max user processes = 10,240
```

Q2:
I also have have the timeout in redis set to 0, tcp-keepalive set to 60, and tcp-backlog set to 65535. I am using predis, and i have timeout there set to 0, and the  read_write_timeout set to -1. However, we periodically keep getting the error below.

```
2015-10-28 11:24:14     406309  cron-web        Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://10.0.0.1:6379]
2015-10-28 19:15:13     0       web-billing-3   Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://10.0.0.1:6379]
2015-10-28 19:56:58     0       web-billing-3   Operation timed out [tcp://10.0.0.1:6379]
2015-10-29 10:02:25     437257  web-billing-1   Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://10.0.0.1:6379]
2015-10-29 12:03:54     439897  cron-web        Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://10.0.0.1:6379]
2015-10-29 15:06:23     443772  web-billing-3   Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://10.0.0.1:6379]
```

I have tried changing the timeout inroads to 300 and still does not work. The linux system params are also set as demonstrated in question 1. All this has not helped the situation. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this scenario has happened before w/PRedis and it could be the way it uses connections leading to IP connection tracking on the server getting overloaded. Or your scripts are firing up "too many" connections. Either way you can figure out fairly easily if this is the case.

On the Redis server, run `dmsg| grep conntrack`. If you see messages like `ip_conntrack: table full, dropping packet` then this is the problem. You can follow the steps in [this article](https://major.io/2008/01/24/ip_conntrack-table-full-dropping-packet/) to fix it via altering your `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_conntrack_max` settings to match/exceed the peaks you are seeing in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_count`.

Ultimately though this *probably* belongs on Superuser as it is likely to be a system-level issue.

Edit:
For determining concurrent connections you need to look at `info clients` and look at the current connections count. You'll need to track that over time to determine what the concurrency profile is in order to see if it could be the issue. Clearly the finer grained resolution you run (ie. the more often you check-and-store) the better your chances of catching a concurrency spike will be.

I really suspect the problem is with Predis as it has known connection management issues. if you can, try using phpredis to see if it continues to occur.

Comment: The output i get is [11351916.175115] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max). On my redis instance, when i run "redis-cli info stats", i have over 11 million total_connections_received. My redis timeout is set to 0, and the tcp-backlog is set to 65535. tcp-keepalive is set to 60.

Comment: The `total_connections_received` stat is just a counter, it doesn't cover concurrent connection counts which is probably more what you're needing to discover.

Comment: I am tracking concurrent connections too. But i would like to get some feedback on whether the output  {{{[11351916.175115] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)}}}  means there is a problem since i did not get the like {{{ip_conntrack: table full, dropping packet}}}